# Laravel rules Error using Laravel-build-form package

Tags: php, laravel

i have validate rules error, but I don’t understand why he shows like this even though I write more than 1900

Im using https://kristijanhusak.github.io/laravel-form-builder/ this package

Build Form

```
class TruckForm extends Form
{
    public function buildForm()
    {
        $this
            ->add('brand_id','collection', [
                'type' => 'select',
                'rules' => 'required',
                'property' => 'name',
                'options' => [
                    'choices' => Brand::pluck('name')->toArray()
                ]
            ])
           ->add('year', 'number', [
               'rules' => ['required', 'min:1900', 'max:'.Carbon::now()->year]
           ])
           ->add('owner_full_name', Field::TEXT, [
               'rules' => ['required', new MinWordsRule(2)]
           ])
           ->add('number_of_owners', Field::NUMBER, [
               'rules' => 'nullable'
           ])
           ->add('comment', Field::TEXTAREA, [
               'rules' => 'nullable'
           ])
           ->add('Save or Create', Field::BUTTON_SUBMIT,
                [
                    'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-success']
                ]
           );

    }
}
```

Screen Error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Validatore is misinterpreting the datatype of year for a string that's why it says

"*the year Must be at least 1900 characters*".

Try to define the year as `Field::NUMBER` like `'number_of_owners'`

and change the `min` `max` to `gt` '*greater than*' and `lte` '*less than or equal*':

```
 ->add('year', Field::NUMBER, [
           'rules' => ['required', 'gt:1900', 'lte:'.Carbon::now()->year]
       ])
```